# Get directories for UNC root

Tags: vb.net, filesystems

I am attempting to use `Directory` to get lists of subdirectories from UNC drives.  I have the following paths.

\test-1
\test-1
\test-3

When I attempt to run the following code, I get an error

```
Dim directories() As String

directories = Directory.GetDirectories("\\test-1\")
```

The error I get is: 
The UNC path should be of the form \server\share.

Is there any way for me to get to the list of directories on \test-1\?  I understand that it's a share, but I do not have access to the complete network path to the machine hosting it.

I can get where I want to go by using the `FolderBrowserDialog`, but I'd like to do this without it.

Answer (score 0):

It's the double backslash that's confusing things...

The error message is correct... a valid UNC path looks like:
\\ServerName\ShareName\Folder

So, most likely you're really trying to get subdirectories of:

- \\ServerName\ShareName\test-1
- \\ServerName\ShareName\test-2
- \\ServerName\ShareName\test-3

So, you just have to figure out what the server name and share names are! ...Unless "\test-1" *is* the server name

Comment: It is interesting that the folder browser knows what to do with it.  If I create a folder browser and pass it \\test-1 as the selected path, it brings it up.  Unfortunately, folder browser does not give me any more useful information.

Test-1, Test-1, and Test-3 probably reside on separate servers.  Unfortunately, it looks like I'm out of luck doing what I'd like to do.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: So, are you saying that you really need to enumerate the shares that exist on the \\test-1 server?